# Set FileSystemAccessRule for "IIS AppPool\Name" permissions fails with "Some or all identity references could not be translated"

Tags: c#, permissions, iis-7.5

I'm programmatically cloning a git repo, compiling the source & creating a new site in IIS on an R2 2008 Windows server.

Once the site is configured I need to set the permissions for the new IIS AppPool Identity account; I'm trying to use `FileSystemAccessRule` :

```cs
// Set the Permissions
var dSiteRoot = new DirectoryInfo(cSiteRoot);

var oACL = dSiteRoot.GetAccessControl();
var cUser = "IIS APPPOOL\\" + cAppPoolName;

oACL.AddAccessRule(
    new FileSystemAccessRule(
        cUser, 
        FileSystemRights.FullControl, 
        InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, 
        PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, 
        AccessControlType.Allow
    )
);

dSiteRoot.SetAccessControl(
    oACL
);
```

An exception is thrown when the new instance of `FileSystemAccessRule` is created with the following message :

> *Some or all identity references could not be translated.*

I wondered if the user hadn't been created; having just created & committed the AppPool & Site via `ServerManager`.   <s>So I tried to reference another, existing & active, IIS AppPool user.  That too failed.</s> **EDIT** : *I mustn't have tested this correctly - see my answer below*

I did wonder if I needed the machine name prepending to the string.  I tried to prepend the MachineName, from `System.Environment.MachineName`, but that too failed with the same error.

How can I reference an IIS AppPool User to set permissions on a Folder using C#?

Answer (score 1):

The Above C# is correct, and I was wrong, it's down to the timing.

I added a loop into that tries to set the permissions via `AddAccessRule` if it fails I set the thread to sleep for 50ms before trying again & so on until my timeout is reached or it's successful; in all cases it's been successful with 5 attempts.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question! I guess before this code you tried to create an app pool and set permissions for one of its folders (like me). I was struggling with the same issue and I had to add `await Task.Delay(250)` before setting permissions. It looks like it is caused by the fact that when you create an application pool and assign some ApplicationPoolName, the user account is not created immediately. Some asynchronous process starts under the hood, but perhaps we don't have a proper way to determine when it is ready. It looks like that this delay is an ugly but only solution.